# Validations on dynamic php grid with check boxes and text fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, validation

[image]

I have following data to show from data base, it is no ok.

```
<table class="table-style-one" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="margin:0 auto;">
              
              <thead style="color:black;">
                <th style="text-align:center;">S.N</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">PO REFERENCE</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>ITEM NAME</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>UNIT</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>QUANTITY IN STOCK</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>FROM THIS</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>THIS QUANTITY</strong></th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php
                $i=1;
        while($rs_rows=mysql_fetch_array($result_of_SQL_GET_POREF_FOR_ITEM))
                {
                  ?>
                  <tr <?=$bg?>>
                    <td align="center" style="padding-top:5px;">
                      <?=$i?>
                    </td>
                    <td width="54%" align="center" style="padding-top:5px;"> <font color="#000000"><?=$rs_rows['po_reference_name'];?>
                    </font> </td>
                    <td width="54%" align="center" style="padding-top:5px;"> <font color="#000000"><?=$rs_rows['item_name'];?>
                    </font> </td>
                    <td width="54%" align="center" style="padding-top:5px;"> <font color="#000000"><?=$rs_rows['unit_name'];?>
                    </font> </td>
                    <td width="54%" align="center" style="padding-top:5px;"> <font color="#000000"><?=$rs_rows['Total_Quantity'];?></font></td>
                    <td width="54%" align="center" style="padding-top:5px;"> <font color="#000000">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?=$rs_rows['po_refrence_id'];?>">
                    </font></td>
                    <td width="54%" align="center" style="padding-top:5px;">
                      <font color="#000000"><input type="text" name="txt[<?=$rs_rows['po_refrence_id'];?>]"></font>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                  $i++;
                }
                ?>
                <tr class="text">
                  <td colspan="7"><div align="center">
                    <p>
                      <input type="hidden" name="req" value="<?=$req?>">
                      <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="submit" tabindex="3"  >
                      <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Cancel" class="submit" tabindex="4">
                      <?php
                      if(isset($_GET[msg])) echo "<font color=red>".$_GET[msg]."</font>";
                      // if(isset($messsag)) echo $messsag;

                      ?>
                    </p>
                  </div></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody></table>
```

this is the form where users issue the quantity to users, let suppose the requested quantity is 10, then it is upto admin to issue this 10 items from one po reference, or some quantity from po-laptop-hp-1 and some from po-dell-hp-1. I want to validate that before submitting it should be validate that quantity entered by user in text field for each row is less then the quantity in stock. the sum of all text field quantity is not more than requested quantity. and else....

i have write this code, but not working as i expected,

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
  if ($_GET[add]==0)
  {
    if($_GET['req']=="") $abc= $_POST['req'];
    if($_POST['req']=="") $abc= $_GET['req'];
    echo $abc;
    $quantity_issued = $qty;
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
      foreach ( $_POST['txt'] as $key => $value )
      {
        echo 'Textbox #'.htmlentities($key).' has this value: ';
        echo htmlentities($value);
      }
      $SQL_Query_Get_Item_Quantity = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE po_refrence_id = '".$selected."'");
      if($SQL_Query_Get_Item_Quantity === FALSE){
        die(mysql_error());
      }
      else{
        $result_SQL_Query_Get_Item_Quantity = mysql_fetch_assoc($SQL_Query_Get_Item_Quantity);
        if($quantity_issued > $result_SQL_Query_Get_Item_Quantity['quantity'] && $result_SQL_Query_Get_Item_Quantity['quantity'] != 0){
          echo 'quantiy you want to issued is more than the quantity that this po refrence holds';
        }
        else{
          //echo $result_SQL_Query_Get_Item_Quantity['quantity']."</br>";
          echo 'quantiy you want to issued is less than the quantity that this po refrence holds';
        }
      }

    }
```

UPDATED:

I have done most of the work on this , the remaining is that i have to validate before save button pressed, is that the quantity entered in the text box is less than the quantity of the row/po reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using jquery validate plugin.
you need to call remote method of jquery validate plugin that works same as ajax.
so that you can check whether quantity entered by user in text field is less then the quantity in stock or not.

[Jquery validate plugin - remote method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)

```
 $( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: "check-email.php"
    }
  }
});
```